# Mysql query returns no results

Tags: php, mysql

The original problem i had was i was not getting stuff to display, now i have stripped back so it is basic

```
$host="localhost";
$user="*";
$pass="*";
$db="*";

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die ("Could not connect to database " . mysqli_connect_error($con));

$query="SELECT * FROM customers WHERE client='$tmp1'";
$results=mysqli_query($con,$query);
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($results);

printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);
```

when i use num rows all i get it saying "Result set has 0 rows."

i ain't sure why i ain't getting any results at all as the query run in phpmyadmin getting the results

Comment: Updated the question as the problem although the original code was poor design and i had calling problems this is now basic and there is no results coming from the database so the problem is not with the connection getting called now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$con` does not exist inside your function. To pull it in the variable scope of the function you need to add this:

```
function getinfo($tmp1,$tmp2)
{
  global $con;
  // rest of your function.
}
```

Side note:

this is very, very bad program design. Do you intend to include this file for every input you want have a default value? Get the information from the database one time, store it in variables and just use `value="<?=$var?>"` in your inputs.

Comment: $con is called in from include 'db.php' i will have to reevaluate the program to see if requires it every time or just once, i am pretty sure why i did it like this was because it could be different values for each but i need to review if that is the case

Comment: after much testing this is what caused my function issue but i also had a issue witht eh connection once that was fixed applying this fixed the function thank you

Answer (score 0):

You didnt set the variable `$tmp3` as return of the function. It simply does not exists outside the function.

I noticed now, that you are also calling global variable inside function which does not exists.

You can set the variable in function like refference

```
function getinfo($tmp1,$tmp2, &$tmp3)    {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE client='{$tmp1}'";

    $results = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["con"], $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
      $tmp3 = $row['$tmp2'];
    }
}
```

Then calling:

```
getinfo("test", "title", $tmp3);
```

`$tmp3` is filled by that function.

Or, ju just forgot to set Output of the function.

```
$tmp3 = getinfo("test","title");
```

Comment: $con is called in from include 'db.php'

Comment: But the variables does not transport to function scope. You must call it from globlals.

Comment: oh..... well that one thing i have learned today i only know a small fraction of php language

Answer (score 0):

Why you include whole code in attribute also your function is returning values so get it into an variable and echo getting var:-
try

```
<?php
include 'function.php'; 
$tmp3 =getinfo("test","title"); 
?>
Title: <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo (!empty($tmp3) ? $tmp3 : '');  ?>"><br>
<?php $tmp4 = getinfo("test","background");?>
<option value="test" <?php if(!empty($tmp4) && $tmp4 == 'test'){echo 'selected = "selected"';}?>>Test</option>
<?php mysqli_close($con);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

### You are not returning the value back from your **getinfo()** function.

It should be `$tmp3 = getinfo("test","title");` instead of just calling `getinfo("test","title");`

Furthermore, you don't need to have such a messy HTML+PHP. Do your including at the beginning of the page. For example:

```
<?php

include 'function.php';
$value = getinfo('test', 'title');
mysqli_close($con);

?>

Title: <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><br>
```

Comment: the reason i did not put them at the top is teh same reason now, i tried that but for some reason when i put it at the top of the page it causes it to produce a white screen remove it or comment it out it is fine